# DataSet Object for the Google Fit API

Tags: android, api

Working with the Google Fit API at the moment and having a bit of trouble with the Sessions API. I'm trying to insert a session for my app's workouts but the documentation is a bit confusing.

In this code snippet is an example from Google's info page. Where exactly do you get DataSet objects from and/or how do you create them from existing data?﻿

```
    // Create a session with metadata about the activity.
    Session session = new Session.Builder()
            .setName(SAMPLE_SESSION_NAME)
            .setDescription("Long run around Shoreline Park")
            .setIdentifier("UniqueIdentifierHere")
            .setActivity(FitnessActivities.RUNNING)
            .setStartTime(startTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setEndTime(endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    // Build a session insert request
    SessionInsertRequest insertRequest = new SessionInsertRequest.Builder()
            .setSession(session)
            .addDataSet(runningDataSet)  //where does this come from???
            .build();
```

Here is a link to Google Sessions API page (which is what I'm using for this code):

[Google Fit API (Sessions API)](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataSet` comes from a `DataSource`, so you will have to create a DataSource first, then simply DataSet.create(yourDataSource);

For example:

```
  DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
                .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                .setDataType(exerciseDataType)
                .setName(exercise.name)
                .setAppPackageName(this)
                .build();

  DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);

  ...

  dataSet.createDataPoint()....insert values :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same thing right now.

If you want to see a full samples using Google Fit API, you can visit the following link: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit.

The missing code you are looking for is

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    // Set a range of the run, using a start time of 10 minutes before this moment,
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -10);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    // Create a data source
    DataSource runningDataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(this.getPackageName())
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_SPEED)
            .setName(SAMPLE_SESSION_NAME + "-running speed")
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    float runSpeedMps = 10;
    // Create a data set of the running speeds to include in the session.
    DataSet runningDataSet = DataSet.create(runningDataSource);
    runningDataSet.add(
            runningDataSet.createDataPoint()
                    .setTimeInterval(startTime, startTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .setFloatValues(runSpeedMps)
    );
```