# Real Time Google Fit Sessions

Tags: google-fit

I'm working on a fitness activity tracker app, and I have a couple questions regarding the Google Fit Sessions API.

From the [Google Fit Session guide](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions), if we want to create a session with real time data, we need to specify start-time using the method `Session.Builder.setStartTime(long,TimeUnit)`, and then we call the method `startSession`.

**Question 1**: Can we set the end time for that session if we're using the real time data? If we've already defined the endTime, do we still need to call the `stopSession` method?

In the documentation, a sample session is created with a specified start-time and end-time, and then sample data are added to that session.

**Question 2**: How would you create a `SessionInsertRequest` on sessions with real time data? How can we get a real time recorded `DataSet` from the `DataSource` to use in the `SessionInsertRequest.Builder.addDataSet(DataSet)` method?

**Question 3**: I already have this method to find my `DataSource`s; do I still need to create a new `DataSource` object to get a `DataSet` object (as answered in this thread: [DataSet Object for the Google Fit API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845253/dataset-object-for-the-google-fit-api))?

The method:

```java
private void findFitnessDataSources() {
    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .build())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + dataSourcesResult.getStatus().toString());
                    for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
                        Log.i(TAG, "Data Source type: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());

                        //Let's register a listener to receive Activity data!
                        if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                                && mListener == null) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Data source for LOCATION_SAMPLE found!  Registering.");
                            registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource,
                                    DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    //just temporarily return datasource for testing purpose
}
```

**Question 4**: How do I modify my method to return the `dataSource`(s) to use in the Session Builder?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, are you able to figure out how to use Sessions api in real time. Any help will be appreciated.